# Zxing NotFoundException with Barcode 128C

Tags: java, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner, code128

I try to use Zxing to decode 128C (Code set C) barcodes. I have success when I read other types like QR_CODE, UPC_A.

These are barcodes that I trying to read:

[image]

[image]

Is possible read 128C barcodes (Not CODE 128 pure) with Zxing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short aswer, yes, it should **is** possible. As 128C just is a subset of 128. Can scan the codes, might take a few seconds. And have XZing working in a app.

You have found out that 128 is supported, now you got to make an translation. 128C takes the same input as 128, just turns out numbers. So you could make a translation from the data you get back, and turn it into 128C. Check the second link for how that translates.

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/README.md

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128

Get the needed classes from the XZing github, put them in a package in the java part of your project. I used only 2:

- IntentIntegrator
- IntentResult

Here is how it is initiated in my code:

```
/**
* Method called to intiate the scan (it's linked to a button)
*/
public void doScan(View view) {
    IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
}

// when you click the Scan Bar Code button
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (scanningResult != null) { // we have a result


           String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents(); // set the content of the scan.
           String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName(); // set the type of scan.

           // You will want to put this data somewhere else, globals, etc.

        } else {
            toast("No scan data received!"); // call to make a toast
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried with Zxing but I received a NotFoundException. I believe it is something in the ZXing algorithm. Can you read these barcodes in your app ?

Comment: The code generated here works: (tested 128 and 128C)

http://example.barcodephp.com/html/BCGcode128.php

Comment: Does your app crash at startup? Mine needed the barcode scanner installed on the app to scan. / I'll post how I did mine.

Comment: Just tried the barcodes you have provided, I can scan them. So that works. Time for some sample code. Good luck!

Comment: Glad to help! Have fun!